# 'Edit' option disabled while 'First posts' review

Tags: support

I know there are a [few cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled) when the Edit option is disabled for a question/answer.

But recently I received a question in the First Posts review queue, where Edit option was disabled (screenshot below)!

[image]

I was wondering if it is due to the reasons cited in the link above, or is it a special case? I haven't ever noticed this for review queues before.

Kindly throw some light.

EDIT: Link to the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9513703) as asked in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timeline for the question "[Access Denied while fetching Bitlocker Information using WMI Query in VB.NET in Local system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585060/access-denied-while-fetching-bitlocker-information-using-wmi-query-in-vb-net-in)":

1. [Question submitted at 11:37:09](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32585060/revisions)
2. [Edit-suggestion submitted at 11:46:32](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4575252/bells?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)
3. [You reviewed at 11:47:55](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9513703).
4. [Approved by OP at 11:57:20](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9513734).

As you are below 2K, that suggested edit blocked editing for you.

Comment: Thanks. Just out of curiosity, how did you get those figures (down to the nearest second) for each activity?

Comment: Try hovering over the displayed time.